# Question overlaps sidebar on Google Chrome

Tags: bug, status-norepro

The question overlaps to the sidebar as can be seen that the word 'website' overlaps the word 'ASKED', using Google Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107
on Ubuntu 12.04

**EDIT**
My screen resolution is 1024x600

[image]

Comment: [Looks fine to me](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133489/why-does-logging-in-to-my-wp-admin-redirect-to-my-homepage) in Chrome 32 on Windows 8

Comment: Could it be because I only have a screen resolution of 1024x600?

Comment: @lozadaOmr - No repro with Chrome 32.0.1700.107 on Windows 7. Will need to check on a VM when I can. Unlikely to be a resolution issue, however.

Comment: I'm thinking, it might just be the one word, like in the screen shot 'website', and the rest is fine.